# Twilio Programmable Chat sendMessage return value

Tags: twilio, twilio-programmable-chat

The Twilio Programmable Chat channel 'sendMessage' method returns a promise with a value that appears to be the newly created message's index. However, this is not confirmed in the documentation.

Is this value the actual index and is it a supported feature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Twilio developer Evangelist here.
I have checked with the chat team and can confirm that the `sendMessage` does return the index of the newly made message and is supported.

Here is the updated [chat documentation](http://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/3.0.0/docs/Channel.html#sendMessage__anchor).